# Livecode revdberr invalid database connection

Tags: ios, mysql, livecode

The simulator and the actual iPhone are giving me this error when trying to make the connection to the database.

> revdberr invalid database type

My database is the mysql service that comes with the livecode hosting.
I can run the app fine from my Mac and from my PC, but simulator and phone gives the error.

I have checked the Mysql external under standalone application settings.

The line of code I am using is

```
put revOpenDatabase("MySQL", tDatabaseAddress, tDatabaseName, tDatabaseUser, tDatabasePassword) into tResult
```

My LC version is 7.1.0 Indy and Xcode 6.4

Another thing to note is that it gives me the error while disconnected from the internet also, so something is happening before even trying to connect.

Going crazy here :)

Comment: I assume you did set the variables first like in the example on runrev.com? http://lessons.runrev.com/m/4071/l/7003-connecting-to-a-mysql-database

Comment: Please, post the entire relevant part of the script, not just the line with the revOpenDatabase function.